# can't write json file to hdfs with spark writestream

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am sending json message to apache spark and I can writestream in console. Bu I can't write it in hdfs.

spark version: 2.3.0

I am using spark-shell
./spark-shell --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.0

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "IP:9092").option("subscribe", "test").load()

df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)").writeStream.queryName("test").outputMode("append").format("json").option("path","file:/node1:8020/test/").option("checkpointLocation", "file:/node1:8020/test/").start().awaitTermination()
```

I don't see any error in terminal screen. But I don't see anything in folder file:/node1:8020/test/. I really spend too much time for this please any help can be good.

thanks

Comment: file:/node1:8020/test/ is this path is correct ..are you getting some error...normally file path is like file:///node1:8020/test/. secondly will it be file or hdfs:///node1:8020/test/

Comment: I am not getting error, it is really wierd. After I write the df.selectExpr command it just wait. I changed  file:///node1:8020/test/  to still same :(

Comment: hdfs:///node1:8020/test/  also try this

Comment: When I add this I get error because of it I used file. error is ```Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: org.apache.hadoop.HadoopIllegalArgumentException: Uri without authority: hdfs:/node1:8020/test/_spark_metadata```

Comment: I think it makes connection with hdfs but cant write it in hdfs

Comment: shows stage 0 but then does not show. problem is in stage part

Comment: can you also try node1:8020/test/ or /node1:8020/test/. https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Uri-without-authority-hdfs-data-spark-metadata-error-when/td-p/182553

Comment: ```org.apache.hadoop.fs.InvalidPathException: Invalid path name Path part /node1:8020/test/_spark_metadata from URI /node1:8020/test/_spark_metadata is not a valid filename.``` I get this error when I used this /node1:8020/test/. ``` Relative path in absolute URI: node1:8020/test```  when I used this node1:8020/test/

Comment: I checkthe hdfs log I think hdfs blocks the spark.                                                        
  INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: BLOCK* fsync: /user/spark/applicationHistory/local-1631801213320.inprogress for DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1836100533_1

Comment: ooo god d*%& I am half pissed off and half happy. It was writing under root folder.